# What Cosmetic Items can you get for free?

Tags: achievements, runescape

I recently completed a quest, [The Death of Chivalry](https://runescape.wiki/w/The_Death_of_Chivalry), and unlocked the cosmetic armors "Dulcin Armour" and "Templar Armour", which got me to wondering... What other cosmetic items can be unlocked through gameplay, without paying for them in Solomon's Store?

I understand there are a few free overrides given to members, such as a home teleport spell animation, but I don't much care for it and would very much like to replace it for free as well. Though, honestly, I am a collector of such things and would appreciate if you could tell me ALL of the unlockables, if there are any others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are others.

- The [circus costumes](https://runescape.wiki/w/Balthazar_Beauregard%27s_Big_Top_Bonanza#Circus_Costumes) are cosmetic rewards from doing the Circus D&D
- The [Book of Faces](https://runescape.wiki/w/Book_of_Faces) is a free cosmetic headpiece
- The [Crab Claw](https://runescape.wiki/w/Crab_Claw) is obtainable from completing the Easy Daemonheim Tasks
- The Bloodied and Honourable [Kyzaj](https://runescape.wiki/w/Kyzaj), after completing The Mighty Fall
- [Dr Nabanik's old trilby](https://runescape.wiki/w/Dr_Nabanik%27s_old_trilby) is a cosmetic hat from completing Mahjarrat Memories
- [Helm of Zaros](https://runescape.wiki/w/Helm_of_Zaros) and [Crest of Seren](https://runescape.wiki/w/Crest_of_Seren) after depositing the memoriam crystals for both gods

There are some free ones that are discontinued, however:

- [Valkyrie helmet](https://runescape.wiki/w/Valkyrie_helmet) and the [Valkyrie spear](https://runescape.wiki/w/Valkyrie_spear) (Obtainable from the 2014 Winter event)
- [Superhero outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Superhero_outfit) and [Superior hero outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Superior_hero_outfit)
- [Turkey hat](https://runescape.wiki/w/Turkey_hat)
- [Hiker outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Hiker_outfit)
- [Sword of Edicts](https://runescape.wiki/w/Sword_of_Edicts_(skin))
- Weapon overrides from [The Bird and the Beast](https://runescape.wiki/w/The_Bird_and_the_Beast/Rewards#Weapon_overrides) and [Battle of Lumbridge](https://runescape.wiki/w/Battle_of_Lumbridge/Rewards#Weapon_overrides)

Comment: I feel like there's more than this from quests, but at this moment I have nothing to evidence that thought. :< Thanks for the information though!

Comment: @Aceofgods Yep, you're right. There's post-quest rewards from Fate of the Gods, and a reward from Mahjarrat Memories. I've added them in the answer